# Layout positioning is changing in nexus

Tags: android-layout, android

I have designed a layout with respect to xhdpi specifications. its working fine in all xhdpi devices. But the layout positioning changes in nexus due to its navigation bar which comes on screen. How can I solve this issue and have the same look and feel in of UI in nexus.

Can we remove the bottom navigation bar from galaxy nexus.

Comment: Which Nexus are you talking?

Comment: do you mean look is different in graphical layout and device|emulator

Comment: @Sandy09 ya in device its positioning is changed

Comment: I think you should post your layout in order to give anyone the chance to understand what "it's not working" on your device (I don't know what a Nexus3 is, maybe a Galaxy Nexus?). And you should also elaborate on that "with respect to xhdpi specifications".

Comment: @mr_archano ya its galaxy nexus with resolution 720x1280

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "wrap_content" or "fill_parent" on layout_width and layout_height. You should not use "100dp" or specific variables like that. Generalize your xml codes with constant variables for working on every screen sizes.